# How to resolve this: Android Studio /error/ItemAdapter?

Tags: android, methods, position

How to resolve this: Android Studio /error/ItemAdapter?

Implements method auto-generated new words, i.e., [position]

From tutorial ([Android Studio For Beginners Part 3](https://youtu.be/rdGpT1pIJlw))

I'm taking a class and need instructions. We are told to just ask this community...

These are all the details I have.

```
package org.ibg.brad.listapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by brad on 12/28/19.
 */

public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String[] items;
    String [] price;
    String [] descriptions;

    public ItemAdapter(Context c, String[] i, String[] p, String[] d) {

        items = i;
        price = p;
        descriptions = d;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }
            //<strong>Here 'int positions' below are auto generated in implementing abstract methods</strong>.
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

            //<strong>How to use 'int position' if I want to get i which I declared the value of as 'items'?</strong>
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = mInflater.(R.layout.my_listview_detail, v)
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);

        String name = items[position];
        String desc = descriptions[position];
        String cost = price[position];

        nameTextView.setText(name);
        descriptionTextView.setText(desc);
        priceTextView.setText(cost);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your error? Any logcat error?

Comment: What is this  `/error/ItemAdapter`?

Comment: Could you add the complete error written in logcat?

Comment: It was: error: <identifier>expected. But I already resolved this issue by adding the word "inflate"  like so... View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_listview_detail, null);

Answer (score 0):

Change line to reflect this: 
View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_listview_detail, null);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s14rQ.jpg)